# Contextual Advertising Software

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, api, plugins

I have taken a project to write an adware (not spyware! this is ethical and legal) program for a company.

Basically what this company wants is to give away free stuff in exchange for people downloading the adware which displays ads when a user browses the internet.

What I have to do is create the program that will open a new instance of IE every time a certain URL is displayed in the address bar.

So if the user goes to http://google.com then a certain ad will pop up (this software is connected to the internet so it knows what to pop up)

My question is where to start? Should I be using VB.NET for this program?

I haven't quite done anything like this, I just want some to point me to a couple of resources on how to get started.

Comment: The concept of ethical unsolicited adware gives some pause but seems a pock mark that's unavoidable these days.  The concept of starting *processes* on the user's machine without a way for her to control it is, still, outrageous.  There's a forum for pr0n site authors somewhere I imagine.

Comment: It was weird for me too. But this is all about 'opting in' to get another useful software for free, in exchange for seeing ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via VB.Net.  You need to use the [InternetExplorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object.  It exposes many properties that allow you to automate IE.

To use these objects you will need to add a COM reference to your project for Microsoft Internet Controls.  Different versions of IE use different dll's; IE7 is ieframe.dll, IE6 is SHDocVw.dll.  To make your code work on both versions you should avoid using any IE7 only features and use late binding / COM interface instead of early binding.

One issue you'll run into is that the InternetExplorer object only creates new instances, it doesn't connect to existing ones.  Here's some code that will allow you to connect to the existing objects:

```
Dim Existing As New List(Of SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)
Dim SWs As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

For Each IE In SWs
    'Add this instance to the list
    Existing.Add(IE)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973764
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735854(v=VS.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188743.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Must the adware be in the form of an IE extension? It can't be a desktop program or stand-alone program?

Comment: "What I have to do is create the program that will open a new instance of IE every time a certain URL is displayed in the address bar." <-- Jimmy Huch. I made an assumption based on your verbiage. Each browser will have different APIs to interact with. You can write one program that will work with all of them, but it'll be larger; or you can write multiple programs with the same basic code and install based on the browser. Choice is yours.